# web search (or search online) from application menu?

Tags: menu, search

May you please help me find out how I can "web search" or "search online" when I open the application menu?

Perhaps this habit created from Windows I can bring over to Elementary OS?

1. Press `meta` key
2. Type `how fast is a turkey?`
3. Default browser is opened and search query is redirected to duckduckgo or google or w/e.

Right now, the only "Action" is to search AppCenter. How do I "search duckduckgo"?

[image: under action or above action web search??]

Answer (score 1):

Elementary app launcher does not have such option.

Comment: After joining the Elementary OS https://discord.gg/pCenUBu I found a must-have app called ulauncher and binded it to f1. https://ulauncher.io/